# parametros POST con window.open

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy intentando abrir una URL pasandole parámetros `POST`.

Según lei, la única forma de hacerlo es utilizando un `<form>`.
Así que he creado un `form` (*con los campos ocultos al usuario*) y los recojo.

El único problema es que al abrir la URL, la abre correctamente, pero no van los datos POST.

¿Podeis ayudarme y decirme por que?
Gracias.

Este es mi form:

```html
<form id="miFormulario" action="../pdf/listado_facturasptes.php" method="post" target='miVentana'>
  <div id="formno" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" id="fecha1hid" name="fecha1hid" value="<?php echo $fecha1 ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="fecha2hid" name="fecha1hid" value="<?php echo $fecha2 ?>">
    <?php
    $comprobar_co = $Usuarios->listarUsuarios("WHERE tipo = 4");
    if($co = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_co)) {
      echo '<div class="form-check">';
      do {
        $idus = $co['id'];
        if(isset($$idus)) {
          $marcarcom = "checked";
        } else {  
          $marcarcom = "";
        }
        echo '<input class="form-check-input" '.$marcarcom.' type="checkbox" value="'.$co['id'].'" name="marcar_cia[]" id="marcar_cia">';
        echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="marcar_cia">'.$co['nombre'].'</label><br>';
      } while($co = mysqli_fetch_array($comprobar_co));
      echo '</div>';
    } else { }
    ?>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="cmdEnviar"  class="btn btn-primary">Generar PDF </button></span>
</form>
```

Y este mi JS:

```
document.getElementById('cmdEnviar').addEventListener('click',function(){
  ventana = window.open('../pdf/listado_facturasptes.php', '_self');
  document.getElementById('miFormulario').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `<form>` tenes que indicar en el atributo `target` el nombre de la ventana. Supongamos `miVentana`.

Luego, es necesario abrir la ventana con el mismo nombre que pusiste en el `target` del `<form>`, es decir, `miVentana`.

Finalmente solo resta enviar el formulario.

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<form id="miFormulario" action="archivo.php" method="post" target="miVentana">
  <input type="text" name="campo" value="valor" />
  <button type="button" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('btnEnviar').addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.open('about:blank', 'miVentana');
    document.getElementById('miFormulario').submit();
  });
</script>
```